# Chrome shortcut to unfocus developer tools

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, developer-tools

Is there a keyboard shortcut to leave Developer Tools *open* in Chrome but to return focus to the main window? (I often need to open devtools to capture some network request, but I need to return to the main part of the window in order to trigger that request, and I'd like to do it all by just using the keyboard.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to focus on the address bar, and then a combination of <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> and <kbd>TAB</kbd> until you focus on the control you want to trigger.

If the Console panel is focused, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> will clear the console instead of focusing on the address bar. In that case, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> twice from the Console panel to focus on the Network panel. From there (or any other non-Console panel), pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> will focus on the browser address bar.

Comment: Thanks! This works great in most places. NB: in the Console tab, it just clears your history.

Comment: Good point. I edited my answer to add a workaround if the Console panel is focused, since F12 will open the Console panel if that is the last that was opened.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>F6</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to focus on the adress bar, then <kbd>Esc</kbd> to focus on the page.